# using jsoup post method in android

Tags: android, authentication, jsoup

I want something like that.i have a button and 2 textbox when user put their username and password and then click on login button then login action will be performed and then welcome the user and go to another page .my code was like that:

```
try {
                Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("URL")
                        .data("log", "abcd", "pwd", "12345", "wp-submit", "প্রবেশ", "redirect_to", "url", "testcookie", "1")
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .execute();
                Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

                Document doc2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("new_url")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .get();

                s = doc2.text().toString();
                t.setText(s);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                t.setText("no");
            }
```

But login action cant be successful and here it always shows "no".
How can i successfully do that???

Comment: added proper permissions in manifest file ?

Comment: i added this to manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: debug your code and check logcat what it says

Comment: give us your `import`s

Comment: I am a beginner in android and i cant understand the debugging here properly ..

Comment: import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;  @Shoshi

Comment: so u r getting `no`. that mean, u r in `catch{}` so do this: `Log.e("tag", e.toString());`. it will show some error in `LogCat`. copy them and give here. @user2029069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is threading problem. because your internet request is on main UI-Thread. test this:

```
private class AsyncExecution extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    boolean tracker = false;
    String s = "";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       try {
           Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.kuetlive.com/wp-login.php")
                        .data("log", "abcd", "pwd", "12345", "wp-submit", "প্রবেশ", "redirect_to", "http://www.kuetlive.com/wp-admin/", "testcookie", "1")
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .settimeout(60000)//time set for the connection 1 min
                        .execute();
                Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

                Document doc2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("http://www.kuetlive.com/wp-admin/profile.php")
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .get();

                s = doc2.text().toString();
                tracker = true;

       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.e("tag", e.toString());
           tracker = false;

       }
     }
  --- // }  // --- i add this by mistake, delete this

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       if(tracker){
            t.setText(s);
       }else{
            t.setText("no");
       }
    }

}
```

and call it as

```
new AsyncExecution().execute();
```

**Edited:**
you cannot perform an internet request on main UI-Thread. that is why u need a different thread. now u could implement a simple thread instead of `AsyncTask`. then why i suggest u to use `AyncTask`. the answer is, u cannot update your UI from a simple Thread. that is why u need `AsyncTask`, because `AsyncTask` gives u flexibility to update UI but execute your method in different Thread beside UI-Thread.

Comment: Don't use a normal thread for this. Use AsyncTask. Big chance you cannot set the text of t.

Comment: my mistake, i totally have forgot that. i am editing my answer @RvdK

Comment: have i make a new class name "AsyncExecution " and then have i to call it as new AsyncExecution().execute(); from my MainActivity's onCreate???isn't it??@Shoshi

Comment: no no no, u should create this class as inner class. like, in MainActivity right after the OnCreate() method create the class, this would be much easier than creating a new class @user2029069

Comment: what should be here-> doInBackground(Void... params) ?? and i m also getting an error of using this @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(tracker){
             t.setText(s);
        }else{
             t.setText("no");
        }
     }

Comment: please consider that i n beginner in android @Shoshi

Comment: I tried your previous code and on LogCat under tag it shows "java.net.SocketTimeoutException"@Shoshi

Comment: @user2029069 : i have edited my answer. an extra `}` was added by my mistake. u should consider that i am writing this code here, not on IDE :) . also remember that `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` methods are under `AsyncExecution` class. and the parameter of `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` are `Void... params` and `Void result` respectively .

Comment: i understand.have i put it "new AsyncExecution().execute();" on my login button onclicklistener ???

Comment: have i call when the user click on login button i mean have i call it like "new AsyncExecution().execute();" in the loginbutton onclicklistner ????

Comment: There is an error on the line "doInBackground(Void... params)"?? It says this result must return a result of type Void so i added "return null;" after Catch statement.Then i have run the app but it still shows "no". please help me about this coz i have tried and Googled many times for it.If u have time please do me a favour    @Shoshi

Comment: if it still says no, then it should print some error in your logcat. i have wrote the `Log.e("tag", e.toString());` statement to print the error in logcat. post your logcat

Comment: it says  java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: @user2029069 : i have set a timeout in the Jsoup Connection. check out answer. if it doesn't help u should turn off your firewall in pc, but keep this change(settimeout) in your code

Comment: Thanx a lot ...yeah in this time it shows something.Could you tell what was wrong with me??Why AsyncExecution and others things were needed here??@Shoshi

Comment: i have added the explanation in my answer. check @user2029069