# android jsoup post data to URL

Tags: java, html, parameters, jsoup

I need to pass data to my URL to get the data.

I have done like this...

```
document= Jsoup.connect("MYURL").data("PASSCODE", "001100").post();
System.out.println(document);
```

but I am not getting proper output

Need help. I have check this Links also
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975399/using-jsoup-post-method-in-android) and [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326812/sending-data-to-server-using-jsoup-android).

Comment: `I am not getting proper output.` Post your out put and what problem is with the output?

Comment: actually after post success of my PASSCODE will display user detail but it not display mean not posting properly data.... so i want to post my PASSCODE

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Comment: it display all data properly but without userdata... i want just check whether it is poosting my PASSCODE or not?

Comment: That is depend on your response, If you pass data successfully then result will be ok other wise some exception will raised.

Comment: no i am not getting any error just nt getting my data

Comment: Try to check if it contains a `Location` header. Maybe you get redirected after a successful request.

Comment: Make sure you are actually sending all the data which website needs. Some forms have hidden fields, which you may need to send too, or maybe you need to send the cookies also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST Data into website using Jsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012399/how-to-post-data-into-website-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 1):

Usually login into a web site requires two steps:

1. You send a get request to get the page, and you extract from there some values like session ID etc, and the cookies.
2. You send a post request with the values from step 1, and your user name and password.

To know which values you need to send, use your browser in the developer mode (by pressing F12) and examine the traffic.

If you want to write an android app, change the user agent string to match your browser, since some sites send different pages to different clients.

You can see an example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871801/problems-submitting-a-login-form-with-jsoup).